# cannot declare instance members in a static class

Tags: c#, static

**EDIT** **ok so i made the class non-static which helped. However now im getting an error that program main.exe does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.**

New to c#. Please help. How do i make this work? The objective of the lesson was to call a function in main. I've only ever programmed in c++.

So i removed the 'static' from the class or tired making the strings public. It still won't work.

I realize this isn't a very efficient program but its mostly a learning exercise.

```
using System;

namespace survey{

static class program {

public string GetName()
{
  Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input name > ");
  string name = Console.ReadLine();

  if (name == "") 

  {
    do {
      Console.Write("Invalid input. Please try again > ");
      name = Console.ReadLine();
       } while ( name == "");
  }
  return name;
}

public string GetYear()
{
  Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input year > ");
  string name = Console.ReadLine();

  if (year == "") 
  {
    do {
      Console.Write("Invalid input. Please try again > ");
      year = Console.ReadLine();
       } while ( year == "");
  }
  return year;
}

public string GetAge()
{
  Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input age > ");
  string age = Console.ReadLine();

  if (age == "") 
  {
    do {
      Console.Write("Invalid input. Please try again > ");
      age = Console.ReadLine();
       } while ( age == "");
  }
  return age;
}

static void Main (string[] args){

Console.WriteLine("\nPlease note\nThis program is only applicable for users born between 1999 and 2010");

string name = GetName();
string year = GetYear();
string age = GetAge();

Console.WriteLine("\nYour name is: " + name);
Console.WriteLine("Your age is: " + age);

 if(year == "1999"){
  Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the rabbit");
}

else if(year == "2000"){
  Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the dragon");
}

else if(year == "2001"){
  Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the snake");
}
else if(year == "2002"){
  Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the horse");
}
else if(year == "2003"){
  Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the goat");
}

else if(year == "2004"){
  Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the monkey");
}

else if(year == "2005"){
  Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the rooster");
}

else if(year == "2006"){
  Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the dog");
}

else if(year == "2007"){
  Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the pig");
}

else if(year == "2008"){
  Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the dragon");
}

else if(year == "2009"){
  Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the ox");
}

else if(year == "2010"){
  Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the tiger");
}

else{
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid year");
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: At which line do you get that error?

Comment: @faithfull ok so i made the class non-static which helped. However now im getting an error that program main.exe does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.

Comment: `Main` is a static function. It cannot access non-static data/functions. Either make the functions `static` or create a `program` object (removing `static` from the class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood correctly what is the intention here but if you want to access members without initiating the object, this is the way to go:

```
namespace survey
{
class program
    {
        private static string year;

        public static string GetName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input name > ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            if (name == "")

            {
                do
                {
                    Console.Write("Invalid input. Please try again > ");
                    name = Console.ReadLine();
                } while (name == "");
            }
            return name;
        }

        public static string GetYear()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input year > ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            if (year == "")
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.Write("Invalid input. Please try again > ");
                    year = Console.ReadLine();
                } while (year == "");
            }
            return year;
        }

        public static string GetAge()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input age > ");
            string age = Console.ReadLine();

            if (age == "")
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.Write("Invalid input. Please try again > ");
                    age = Console.ReadLine();
                } while (age == "");
            }
            return age;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease note\nThis program is only applicable for users born between 1999 and 2010");

            string name = GetName();
            string year = GetYear();
            string age = GetAge();

            Console.WriteLine("\nYour name is: " + name);
            Console.WriteLine("Your age is: " + age);

            if (year == "1999")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the rabbit");
            }

            else if (year == "2000")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the dragon");
            }

            else if (year == "2001")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the snake");
            }
            else if (year == "2002")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the horse");
            }
            else if (year == "2003")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the goat");
            }

            else if (year == "2004")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the monkey");
            }

            else if (year == "2005")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the rooster");
            }

            else if (year == "2006")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the dog");
            }

            else if (year == "2007")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the pig");
            }

            else if (year == "2008")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the dragon");
            }

            else if (year == "2009")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the ox");
            }

            else if (year == "2010")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You were born in the year of the tiger");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid year");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it said to wait 4 minutes~ I'm keeping the tab open so i'll make sure i do it. You were a lot of help!

Comment: perfect, glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the functions static as well, i.e.

```
public static string GetAge() {...}
```

instead of

```
public string GetAge() {...}
```

Comment: + you have a mistake in the GetYear function: the variable name should be 'year' not 'name'.